# kivy - button executing function

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

I'm using Kivy example code to get file path from two different files.
My goal is to use the file path to open and manipulate data from the file.

My problem is to pass the file path into the open file command in the test function below.

**Here is my Code:**

```
from kivy.app import App    
from kivy.uix.button import Button    
from kivy.core.window import Window    
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout    
from kivy.uix.label import Label    

import re    
import pandas as pd

class DropFile(Button):

        def __init__(self, **kwargs):
            super(DropFile, self).__init__(**kwargs)
            # get app instance to add function from widget
            app = App.get_running_app()
            # add function to the list
            app.drops.append(self.on_dropfile)

        def on_dropfile(self, widget, path):
            # a function catching a dropped file
            # if it's dropped in the widget's area
            if self.collide_point(*Window.mouse_pos):
                self.text = path

        def test(self):
            minimum_wage = open(**FILE PATH HERE**)
            LinesToString = ''
            for line in minimum_wage:
                LinesToString += line
            patFinder = re.compile('\d{5}\s+\d{5,9}')
            findPat = re.findall(patFinder, LinesToString)
            empno_list = []
            pattern = '(\d{5})\s+(\d{5})'
            for string in findPat:
                match = re.search(pattern, string)
                empno = match.group(2)
                empno_list.append(empno)
            MinimumWage = pd.DataFrame({'EMPNO': empno_list})
            MinimumWage.set_index('EMPNO')
            print MinimumWage.head()
            print MinimumWage.shape

class DropApp(App):

        def build(self):
            # set an empty list that will be later populated
            # with functions from widgets themselves
            self.drops = []
            # bind handling function to 'on_dropfile'
            Window.bind(on_dropfile=self.handledrops)
            box = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical')
            top_label = Label(text='Data manipulation', font_size=45)
            box.add_widget(top_label)

            run_button = Button(text='Run', size_hint=(1, 0.5))
            run_button.bind(on_press=DropFile.test)
            box.add_widget(run_button)

            two_buttons = BoxLayout(orientation='horizontal')
            dropleft = DropFile(text='Drag & Drop File here')
            # dropright = DropFile(text='right')
            two_buttons.add_widget(dropleft)
            # two_buttons.add_widget(dropright)
            box.add_widget(two_buttons)
            return box

        def handledrops(self, *args):
           # this will execute each function from list with arguments from
            # Window.on_dropfile
            #
            # make sure `Window.on_dropfile` works on your system first,
            # otherwise the example won't work at all
            for func in self.drops:
                func(*args)

DropApp().run()
```

Thanks

Comment: your indentation is broken.

Comment: Damn im trying to fix it but it just keeps breaking the indentation

Comment: @MaxKedem copy code here, select it all, press Ctrl + K

Answer (score 0):

You can call `test()` method at the last line of `on_dropfile()` e.g.:

```
def on_dropfile(self, widget, path):
    # a function catching a dropped file
    # if it's dropped in the widget's area
    if self.collide_point(*Window.mouse_pos):
        self.text = path
        self.test(path)

def test(self, path):
    minimum_wage = open(path)
    LinesToString = ''
    ...
```

or launch already from the existing thing e.g. if you run `test()` separately from the `on_dropfile()` function and you won't change `self.text` property after changing the text:

```
def on_dropfile(self, widget, path):
    # a function catching a dropped file
    # if it's dropped in the widget's area
    if self.collide_point(*Window.mouse_pos):
        self.text = path  # path is assigned to self.text <--

def test(self):
    minimum_wage = open(self.text)  # <-- and you can use it
    LinesToString = ''
    ...
```

Or at the end of `on_dropfile` put it into a separate variable and use that in `open()`.

Comment: Thank you for answering me KeyWeeUsr, but still when i hit the "Run" button the app crush...TypeError: test() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)...got any ideas why?

Comment: @MaxKedem you know there's a [faq](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) about how Q&A works here, right? :P